# Unable to schedule task to copy across network

Tags: network-share, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, scheduler

I remote access into a server running windows 2008 with my login from active directory. I wrote a BAT file to copy from a different sharefolder to backup files to this server. Running the BAT file manually copies the files perfectly. But when I schedule the task it does nothing. Even manually running the scheduled task does nothing either. How can I fix this?

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the task what did you set under 'Security options'?

If the user account is not to be logged in all the time then set this to 'Run whether user is logged on or not' and ticket the 'Run with highest privileges'.

Ensure the user account users for this task has the same permissions as your testing account and check the'Run with highest privileges' box as this will operate as 'Run as Administrator' [found here.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7167bb31-f375-4f77-b430-0339092e16b9/how-does-run-with-the-highest-privileges-really-work-in-task-scheduler-?forum=w7itprogeneral)


The issue appears to be your user account running the task or elevation of UAC to execute this.